# Trouble with importing MathParser external library in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

as above, I cannot get access to classes of external library `MathParser` imported with Maven in IntelliJ. I've configured `pom.xml` file and enabled auto-download, so (as seen on the bottom of Project files section) it got downloaded, but when I try to use classes/import with `import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.*;` - auto and manual import do not work.

Here's a screenshot of current situation

[image]

Any ideas?

Created new project for this test purposes, but same thing is happening. In ,,External Libraries" (in project files on the left in the screenshot)  the lib appears , nevertheless no way to access to it's classes.

Update:

1) I've deleted jdk, and downloaded the newest 10'th - no results. 
2) Reinstalled IntelliJ IDE couple times, same. Also I've tried to set up IntelliJ on Windows in VirtualBox (I need to finish my short project), same with jdk 10, and finally it worked. Nevertheless, I need to make it work without externalising from macOS (also, friend of mine with Mac, didn't have any similar problems). Totally same procedure, but on the macOS side on my Macbook I cannot import anything from this exterbal library (what is possible on virtualised Windows side).

3) I was trying to clean my Mac out of IntelliJ folders, then uninstall it, then imported settings from ,,healthy mac's IntelliJ" - still nothing new.

Solution:
I've reinstalled macOS, and finally that's how I've solved the problem.

Comment: try to righ-click on the POM file and indicate maven > re-import dependencies

Comment: It didn't change anything.

Comment: What dependency do you use in pom.xml? It looks like the wrong jar was downloaded.

Comment: Not rly. I've just openned project friend's of mine, that works, but does not in my IDE. Same structure, same everything. Sth is wrong with config of IDE, no idea what it might be. I've just reinstalled the IDE, 1.8.0_161 SDK, default mudule - still nothing. Atm, I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: Sometimes (very few times) the downloaded JAR file (via maven) is somewhat corrupt (or incomplete, or out of whack) - try to go into your `.m2/repository` folder and manually delete the downloaded library (I usually delete the entire folder for this JAR) - this will force it to download it again.  Everything else seems correct but we only have a screenshot to go by.... let me see if there are other settings to review in the meantime

Comment: Wreidly enoguh it doesn't see content of org file. Maybe there is sth wrong with address to repository - going to read about it, how to check it and where to modify

Comment: That jar doesn't seem to contain any classes.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems to be correct. You can try to

- directly import of `mxParser` by changing import to `import org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser.mxParser` or
- check which classes you have in that package by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> after mXparser package in import statement.

Comment: It says ,,Cannot resolve mxParser", and obviously I don't see anything connected to mxParser on the list. Friends of mine implemented this library, nevertheless they didn't have such a problem. To be honest I'm new to IntelliJ IDE. At the moment I'm wondering, if there is sth in config External Libraries, or jdk, that might be the reason.

Comment: That's strange. Another thing you can try is to delete import statement and press `Alt` + `Enter` on `mxParser`, IDEA should suggest to import class...

Comment: The class is `mXparser` not `mxParser` (case matters), though the dependency clearly shows that it is not downloaded. Do you have maven installed externally? Can you try running `mvn clean package` from external command window to figure out if it is intellij Issue or maven issue?

Comment: It was installed automatically with IntelliJ. Mvc clean works (running it from Maven Panel), but nothing changes. Trying to IntelliJ reinstall atm